# fast fourier transform with complex numbers from a file

Tags: python, signals, fft

My code let a user to introduce an array of numbers  that will be transformed with Fourier. But I want to read this array from a file . How can I do this? I just started to learn python ..

```
import cmath
from scipy.fftpack import fft
f=open("complex.txt","r+")
c=[]
for line in f:
    line=line.split()
    if line:
        line=[complex(i.replace('i','j')) for i in line]
        c.append(line)

def omega(p, q):
    return cmath.exp((2.0 * cmath.pi * 1j * q) / p)

def fft(signal):
    n = len(signal)
    if n == 1:
        return signal
    else:
        Feven = fft([signal[i] for i in xrange(0, n, 2)])
        Fodd = fft([signal[i] for i in xrange(1, n, 2)])
        combined = [0] * n
        for m in xrange(n/2):
            combined[m] = Feven[m] + omega(n, -m) * Fodd[m]
            combined[m + n/2] = Feven[m] - omega(n, -m) * Fodd[m]

    return combined
```

Comment: The code you give looks as if it already attempts to read an array from a file. In what ways is what it does unsatisfactory to you?

Comment: but how can I call function fft of that array? I don;t want when I run the program to insert numbers.

Comment: Your code both (1) pulls in the `fft` function from `scipy.fftpack` and (2) defines its own `fft` function. Are you intending to use your own FFT routine, or to use the one in `scipy`?

Comment: I think I want to use my own FFT

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point; is the problem that you don't know how to call a function in Python? Or is it something specific to reading files and performing Fourier transforms?

Comment: (We're having two interleaved discussions here; I apologize if it's hard to follow...)

Comment: I don't know how to call the function. How to say it,just do fourier for my array

Comment: To call a function `f` with arguments `a`, `b`, `c`, you just say `f(a,b,c)`. If you want to put the result in a variable `d`, you say `d = f(a,b,c)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to do it. If you want,please,add a comment to be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out (see comments above) that Mady's actual difficulty was in *calling a function in Python*, rather than in reading data from a file or Fourier-transforming it. So:

To apply a function `f` to arguments `a`,`b`,`c`, you say

```
f(a,b,c)
```

and if you want to put the result in a variable called `d`, you say

```
d = f(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the current issue you have with your code? Have you tried:

```
for line in f:
    line=line.split()
    if line:
        line=[complex(i.replace('i','j')) for i in line]
        c.append(line)

for signal in c:
    print fft(signal)
```

?

Comment: Thank you! But when I run the program,I have to insert by myself numbers. I would like to be printed the new array without typing anything

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If i run the program now, I have to type some numbers which will be transformed. I don;t want me to type anything. I just want it to read the numbers from a file ,and then to print them transformed. When I press run ,I want to see those numbers . I don;t want the program to take numbers from standard input.